# How to track number of clients with Indy TIdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I want to know the number of current client connections to an Indy 9 TIdTCPServer (on Delphi 2007)

I can't seem to find a property that gives this.

I've tried incrementing/decrementing a counter on the server OnConnect/OnDisconnect events, but the number never seems to decrement when a client disconnects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Turns out my onconnect/disconnect method was working right, but due to a bug in my servers, they didn't exit correctly. Doh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The currently active clients are stored in the server's `Threads` property, which is a `TThreadList`.  Simply lock the list, read its `Count` property, and then unlock the list:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NumClients: Integer;
begin
  with IdTCPServer1.Threads.LockList do try
    NumClients := Count;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Threads.UnlockList;
  end;
  ShowMessage('There are currently ' + IntToStr(NumClients) + ' client(s) connected');
end;
```

In Indy 10, the `Threads` property was replaced with the `Contexts` property:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NumClients: Integer;
begin
  with IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList do try
    NumClients := Count;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
  ShowMessage('There are currently ' + IntToStr(NumClients) + ' client(s) connected');
end;
```

Comment: what happens when you set up Indy to use a thread pool? From what I have been able to determine, the TCP server instantiates the thread pools number of threads (contexts in Indy10). Counting those would then not give you a count active users, but of instantiated threads/contexts...?

Comment: Thanks Remy, that's what I was after. I hadn't understood how to obtain the TList from TThreadList before.

Comment: @Marjan: the `Threads`/`Contexts` list contains the currently active (ie connected to clients) threads/contexts only.  Pooling is managed outside of TIdTCPServer completely (it is handled by the implementation of `TIdThreadMgrPool`/`TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool`), so idle threads/contexts in the pool do not contribute to the `Count`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why using OnConnect and OnDisconnect wouldn't work for you, but what we have done is to create a descendant of TIdCustomTCPServer; to override its DoConnect and DoDisconnect methods and create and use our own descendant of TIdServerContext (a thread descendant that will "serve" a connection).

You make the TIdCustomTCPServer aware of your own TIdServerContext class by:

(**Edit** Added conditional defines to show how to make it work for Indy9)

```
type
// Conditional defines so that we can use the same ancestors as in Indy10 and we
// can use the same method signatures for DoConnect and DoDisconnect regardless 
// of the Indy version. Add other conditional defines as needed.
// Note: for INDY9 to be defined, you need to include the appropriate includes 
// from Indy, or define it in your own include file.
{$IFDEF INDY9}  
  TIdContext = TIdPeerThread;
  TIdServerContext = TIdContext;
  TIdCustomTCPServer = TIdTCPServer;
{$ENDIF}

  TOurContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  private
    FConnectionId: cardinal;
  public
    property ConnectionId: cardinal ...;
  end;

...

constructor TOurServer.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);

  ...
  {$IFDEF INDY10_UP}
    ContextClass := TOurContext;
  {$ELSE}
    ThreadClass := TOurContext;
  {$ENDIF}
  ...
end;
```

In the DoConnect override of our TIdCustomTCPServer descendant we set the ConnectionID of our context class to a unique value:

```
procedure TOurServer.DoConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  OurContext: TOurContextabsolute AContext;
begin
  Assert(AContext is TOurContext);
  HandleGetNewConnectionID(OurContext, OurContext.FConnectionID);

  inherited DoConnect(AContext);

  ...

end;
```

Our DoDisconnect override clears the ConnectionID:

```
procedure TOurServer.DoDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  OurContext: TOurContextabsolute AContext;
begin
  Assert(AContext is TOurContext);
  OurContext.FConnectionID := 0;

  ...

  inherited DoDisconnect(AContext);
end;
```

Now it is possible to get a count of the current connections at any time:

```
function TOurServer.GetConnectionCount: Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
  CurrentContext: TOurContext;
  ContextsList: TList;
begin
  MyLock.BeginRead;
  try
    Result := 0;

    if not Assigned(Contexts) then
      Exit;

    ContextsList := Contexts.LockList;
    try

      for i := 0 to ContextsList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        CurrentContext := ContextsList[i] as TOurContext;

        if CurrentContext.ConnectionID > 0 then
          Inc(Result);
      end;

    finally
      Contexts.UnLockList;
    end;
  finally
    MyLock.EndRead;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about incrementing / decrementing a counter from `OnExecute` (or `DoExecute` if you override that)? That can't go wrong!

If you use `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` you don't even need a critical section to protect the counter.

Answer (score 2):

This should work on Indy 9, but it is pretty outdated nowadays, and maybe something is broken in your version, try to update to the latest Indy 9 available.

I made a simple test using Indy 10, which works very well with a simple interlocked Increment/Decrement in the OnConnect/OnDisconnect event handlers.  This is my code:

```
//closes and opens the server, which listens at port 1025, default values for all properties
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active := not IdTCPServer1.Active;
  UpdateUI;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateUI;
end;

//Just increment the count and update the UI
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  InterlockedIncrement(FClientCount);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, UpdateUI);
end;

//Just decrement the count and update the UI
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  InterlockedDecrement(FClientCount);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, UpdateUI);
end;

//Simple 'X' reply to any character, A is the "command" to exit
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Writeln('Write anything, but A to exit');
  while AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte <> 65 do
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write('X');
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Writeln('');
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Writeln('Good Bye');
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;

//Label update with server status and count of connected clients 
procedure TForm2.UpdateUI;
begin
  Label1.Caption := Format('Server is %s, %d clients connected', [
    IfThen(IdTCPServer1.Active, 'Open', 'Closed'), FClientCount]);
end;
```

then, opening a couple of clients with telnet:

[image: 3 connected clients]

then, closing one client

[image: 2 connected clients]

That's it.

INDY 10 is available for Delphi 2007, my main advise is to upgrade anyway.